# No resource identifier found for attribute 'headerLayout' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, navigation-drawer

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.c22241.emudhrara.RaDashBoardActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Errors:

```
Error:(27) No resource identifier found for attribute 'headerLayout' in     package 'com.example.c22241.emudhrara'
Error:(27) No resource identifier found for attribute 'menu' in package   
com.example.c22241.emudhrara'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\20440\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: xmlns:yourApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.yourAppPackege.yourClass"

Comment: try restarting your android studio.